# Equivalent curl request to c# HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

How to make following curl request in c# HttepClient

curl -X POST “https://api.knurld.io/v1/endpointAnalysis/file” \
 -H "Authorization: $AUTHORIZATION"  \
 -H "Developer-Id: $DEVELOPER_ID"  \
 -H “multipart/form-data”  \
 -F "filename=PATH_TO_FILE"

Answer (score 0):

This Is the sync implemntation but I hope is what you need

```
    public void Send(string auth, string filePath, string developerId)
    {
        string payload = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var content = new StringContent(payload);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Developer-Id", developerId);
            var result = client.PostAsync("https://api.knurld.io/v1/endpointAnalysis/file", content).Result;
            string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
```

Kind Regards

Comment: for async related stuff i want it using HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

For HttpClient:

```
async Task Send(string developerId, string pathToFile, string auth)
    {
        using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient())
        {
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(auth);
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Developer-Id", developerId);
            var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream));
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await c.PostAsync(@"https://api.knurld.io/v1/endpointAnalysis/file", multipartFormDataContent);
                string response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```